# Funcion devuelve casteo con diferente tema

Tags: c, funciones, cast, requests, casting

> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Hola, he tratado este tema por dos días y no he encontrado como solventar que mi función:

```
static void*
fn_multiplicacion_1(void* x, void* y)
{
    int* d_x =  x;
    int* d_y =  y;

    int m = *d_x * *d_y;

    void* r = NULL;
    r = (int *)m;    
    return r;
}
```

Me devuelva la compilación sin *warning*.

la llamada a esta operación la hago de esta forma:

```
int i_x = 7;
int i_y = 2;
p_fnc = fn_multiplicacion_1;
pfnc_x = (int *)p_fnc(&i_x, &i_y);
printf("multiplicacion [%d]\n", pfnc_x);
```

El punto es el siguiente, quiero que mi función `void*` con parámetros `void*` me devuelva un tipo `int*` al realizar la operación; y al comenzar a devolver el puntero declarado para el retorno me aparece advertencia de casteo. Al ejecutar normal y con debbug arroja el resultado de la multiplicación.

Yo no quiero esa advertencia así que probé el origen y varias soluciones suministrada por la red Internet y no he logrado un avance significativo.

Gracia por su animo y colaboración.

Answer (score 2):

El compilador devuelve la advertencia en esta línea:

```c
pfnc_x = (int *)p_fnc(&i_x, &i_y);
```

Si el tipo de la variable `pfnc_x` es `int`, solo se podrá asignar valores que sean de tipo `int`. Para solucionar este warning, debes cambiar el tipo de la variable a `int*`. Sin embargo, el código seguirá teniendo problemas en esta línea:

```c
r = (int *)m;
```

El puntero es de tipo `void*` y le estás asignando un valor de tipo `int`, cuando debería ser de tipo `int*`.

No se puede tomar el puntero como que si fuera una variable que guarda un número entero. **No!** Un puntero almacena una dirección de memoria de X variable. En este caso, el puntero `r` recibe un entero, en la cual, puede coincidir con una dirección de memoria de algún registro (donde se almacene un dato).

Imagínate que después de ejecutar la función `fn_multiplicacion_1` hago lo siguiente:

```c
//Aquí asumo que pfnc_x es de tipo int*
printf("multiplicacion [%d]\n", *pfnc_x);
```

Al colocar el operador de desreferencia (*) accedería a la dirección de memoria al que apunte `pfnc_x`, el problema es que al tratar de leer dicho **contenido** me arriesgo a que ocurra una falla de segmentación, debido a que, es una dirección de memoria (que en realidad para el programador es el resultado de la multiplicación retornada por la función) que al programa no le pertenece, por lo tanto, no es accesible.

Podríamos anteponer el ampersand en la variable `m`:

```c
r = &m;
```

Sin embargo, esto no es recomendable, debido a que, la variable local `m` quedará liberada de memoria cuando la función termine su ejecución, esto quiere decir, que el puntero `pfnc_x` no podrá acceder a dicho contenido, de lo contrario, ocurrirá una [falla de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso).

La **solución** sería usar memoria dinámica (con [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)) de esta forma:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void* fn_multiplicacion_1(void* x, void* y)
{
    int* d_x =  x;
    int* d_y =  y;
    //Reservamos 4 bytes para almacenar un entero
    void* r = malloc(sizeof(int));
    //Si hubo una falla al momento de asignar la memoria
    if(r == NULL)
    {
        printf("Falla de memoria\n");
        return NULL;
    } 
    //Se realiza la multiplicación y mandamos ese dato hacia la dirección de memoria al que apunte (r)
    *(int*)r = *d_x * *d_y;
    return r;
}

int main() 
{
    void* (*p_fnc)(void*, void*);
    int i_x = 7;
    int i_y = 2;
    int* pfnc_x;
    p_fnc = fn_multiplicacion_1;
    pfnc_x = p_fnc(&i_x, &i_y);
    //Si no hubo una falla de asignación.
    if(pfnc_x != NULL)
    {
        //Imprimimos el dato
        printf("multiplicacion [%d]\n", *pfnc_x);
        //Liberamos la memoria 
        free(pfnc_x);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

De esta forma la función retorna una dirección de memoria que si le pertenece al programa y es obligación del programador liberar la memoria con `free`.